# Dynamically populating and setting value in dropdownlist in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form where I have 4 dropdowns Country, State, District and City. Country is populated on form load and rest are populated on selected index changed event. The sequence is On Country's selected index changed States are populated. On State-> Districts populated and on Districts -> Cities are populated.

For saving it worked fine but when i was updating value, it shows null reference error. On debugging I got, the dropdowns are not populated, whereas I was trying set values. Below is my code.

```
using (var manager = new LocationManager())
        {
            var dt = manager.GetLocationById(i);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                Countries.SelectedValue = Countries.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString()).Value;
                BindStates(Convert.ToInt32(Countries.SelectedItem.Value));

                States.SelectedValue = States.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["State"].ToString()).Value;
                BindDistricts(Convert.ToInt32(States.SelectedItem.Value));

                Districts.SelectedValue = Districts.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["District"].ToString()).Value;
               BindCities(Convert.ToInt32(Districts.SelectedItem.Value));

                Cities.SelectedValue = Cities.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["City"].ToString()).Value;
                Pincode.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Pincode"].ToString();

                ViewState["Id"] = dt.Rows[0]["LocationId"].ToString();



            }
        }
```

I am getting error: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} at method

> BindStates(Convert.ToInt32(Countries.SelectedItem.Value));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not with the population of drop downs, but with finding values, when

```
Countries.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString())
```

wont find any matching value it will return null. So applying 'Value' property on null is giving the error.

you can put a null check before selecting it.
something like below:

```
countryDropDown.SelectedValue = countryDropDown.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString()) != null ? countryDropDown.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString()).Value : countryDropDown.Items.FindByText("-Please select-").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if Countries.SelectedItem != null

Comment: Always check if a selected item is not null

Comment: And when using a number that comes from a string convert it using int.TryParse

Comment: i have its text part in database. I have to find and set its respective value

Comment: have you bind all values first to respective drop down, if not bind those values first and then make respective value as selected.

Answer (score 0):

@Amit Ranjan: Bind all values in page init method and at page load make the perticular value selected for all drop downs:

you are getting null reference because, there is no value already bind to the drop down.

At page init bind all values to dropdown 
    
    India
    US
    UK
asp:DropDownList>

At page load

```
DropDownList .SelectedValue= dt.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString()).Value;
```